# Getting link error when using kernel object

Tags: c++

I'm developing on Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm trying to use a kernel object I got (.ko which was developed by other department in my company). The ko is loaded (I can see it via lsmod).

I'm building a C++ program which use the API of the ko.
I added the include path of the ko headers.
I'm getting link error (undefined reference) to the ko functions.

What do I need to add to the compilation, in order to use the ko?

Comment: wait, do you want to invoke code inside the kernel or do you want to use part of the kernel module as a library for your userland application?

Comment: I want to use part of the kernel module as a library in my program.

Comment: Missing `extern "C"`? That said, there's far from enough info to answer your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Well, then you should have that piece build as a static library and then link both your userland program and the kernel module against that library.  You can't treat a kernel module as a library as far as I know.